# How to prove that there exists an $R$-module $E$ and an exact sequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, exact-sequence

This question was asked in my assignment of Commutative algebra and I am not able to make significant progress on it. I am following Algebra by Thomas Hungerford.

> Let $R$ be a ring and let we have a commutative diagram of $R$-modules $\alpha_1 :M_1\to N_1$ and $\alpha_2 :M_2 \to N_2$, in which the two horizontal maps $M_1 \to M_2$ and $N_1 \to N_2$  are injective. Show that there exists an $R$-module $E$ and an exact sequence $$0 → \ker α_1 → \ker α_2 → E → \operatorname{coker} α_1 → \operatorname{coker} α_2 .$$ of $R$-modules.

I don't know which result should I use to move forward to prove what is asked.

Can you please help me?

Comment: There is a short exact sequence starting $M_1\to M_2$, and similarly for $N_i$. The maps $\alpha_i$ then determine a map of short exact sequences, to which we can apply the Snake Lemma.

Comment: I think it's a good exercise to prove this directly without applying the snake lemma, if you haven't done so before. You already know you have a map from $M_1$ to $M_2$; can you prove that it maps $\ker(\alpha_1)$ to $\ker(\alpha_2)$?